# Can Fractured mesh offset along curve in Animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

I want a help, I want to transform a fractured object along curve procedurally in animation nodes.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! What is *"fractured object"*? Can you share any reference on what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am confused. Do you mean rips in your mesh? If so and if you want to fix the rip, select the entire mesh, press W and remove doubles, before ever rendering. You might have doubles in vertrice. That happens, whenever you use mirror modifier. When you finished with modeling or retopology, always be sure to remove doubles in your mesh, always before rendering.

Comment: Hi Omar and Rita. Thanks for supporting me. I want to do as this video but use along a curve instead of offset node https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgLrxg-DSfU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your objects to a collection and record their initial transforms in an ID Key. Then use a *Follow Spline Action* combined with a *Delay Action* and maybe other actions depending on what you need:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Fantastic. It works, Can I ask another 2 questions?  1.when objects start to follow spline can we use like a object controller to change stating order? 2. can we twist arround spline when follow spline? Thank you verry much to helped me

Comment: @UDARAARAVINDA To change the starting order just sort the objects based on your need. For instance, if you shuffle the objects list, the objects will have a random start time. Twisting around the spline is rather computationally expensive and not very easy to do. So I think this is better suited as a separate question.

Comment: Thank you very much Omar. you solved my question clearly

Comment: @UDARAARAVINDA Glad I could help. Make sure to accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Hi!. I want like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njkHH4_z77A&t=144s time(0:36) can objects follow the path like this order in animation nodes?

Comment: @UDARAARAVINDA Please ask a separate question if you have further questions.