# fractured object meshes follow along path in order in AN

Tags: animation-nodes

I want fractured object meshes to follow a path in a defined order in Animation Nodes, like in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njkHH4_z77A&t=144s).

Here is a gif of the animation: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an *ID Key* to define an order using the selection tools as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

To use those indices to define the delay order of a follow spline action, you can can simply sort the objects based on the indices as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Thats wonderfull work. can I move cubs along a curve instead of scale? actually I want to use this technic in to this work https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/130334/68233

Comment: as my guide video I wanted to reffer into 36th second https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njkHH4_z77A&t=144s

Comment: @UDARAARAVINDA Extended my answer.

Comment: wonderful. I'm sorry to ask like this question,how do you use circle selection tool here? I can only use it in edit mode ,in object mode it doesn't select

Comment: @UDARAARAVINDA Using the C shortcut, not sure why it is not working for you. Also, please accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much.it works,I really appreciate you,my blender 2.8 version has a problem it is not get selection order but it works in 2.79.Thank you verry much